# Change the URL of a docker-machine

Tags: azure, docker, docker-machine

I created a machine via `docker-machine create -d azure --azure-static-public-IP`. But what I did is I intentionally changed the public IP address of that VM. With this move, I can not `docker-machine ssh` or any docker-machine related command. Seems like it’s still sending request to the previous public-IP. How can I change that IP and convert it to the new one? I tried `docker-machine regenerate-certs` and even changing the config.json but nothing going to be happened…

The only way I saw fixing this is to reverting back the previous public IP of that VM

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine with a change of the IP in "config.json". For Example, if i have to change my IP on my default docker-machine, i would go here:

```
/Users/arne/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json
```

Adjust the IP and run

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs myVM
```

This should work.

Comment: How will I change the `config.json`?

Comment: I meant what will I add/change in `config.json`? I also attempted that but cannot see anything in the internet

Comment: I would go with  "IPAddress": "192.168.99.100" to your new public ip

Comment: Can you post it to be specific? I actually already tried that, and then what?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when you run `Docker-machine ssh` got this error:

> Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the
>   certs: There was an error validating certificates for host
>   "13.91.60.237:2376": x509: certificate is valid for 40.112.218.127,
>   not 13.91.60.237 You can attempt to regenerate them using
>   'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'. Be advised that this will
>   trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop running containers.

In my test lab, my first IP address is `40.112.218.127`, then I change it to `13.91.60.237`, get this error.

Then I use this command to regenerate it:`docker-machine regenerate-certs jasonvmm`, like this:

```
[root@jasoncli@jasonye jasonvmm]# docker-machine regenerate-certs jasonvmm
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): y
Regenerating TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Installing Docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
[root@jasoncli@jasonye jasonvmm]# docker-machine ssh jasonvmm
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

208 packages can be updated.
109 updates are security updates.


Last login: Fri Dec  8 06:22:09 2017 from 167.220.255.48
```

Also, we can use this command to check the new settings:`docker-machine env jasonvmm`

```
[root@jasoncli@jasonye jasonvmm]# docker-machine env jasonvmm
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://13.91.60.237:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/root/.docker/machine/machines/jasonvmm"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="jasonvmm"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval $(docker-machine env jasonvmm)
```

Please use this script to regenerate them `docker-machine regenerate-certs VMname`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is it just gets stuck on the `Waiting for SSH to be available...` part. So I can not regenerate-certs as well. The way I see it, it still requests to `tcp://my.previous.public.ip`

Comment: 10 minutes and the returns `exit status 255`.

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada run that script with root permission?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you meant by root permission. Root permission on the machine or local machine?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada I mean local machine:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160774/discussion-between-dean-christian-armada-and-jason-ye-msft).